# How connect Google Colab to Cassandra?

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, google-colaboratory, databricks

I've been trying to connect Google Colab to Cassandra for several days, but it always gives the same error. The code I try to run is as follows:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster(['192.168.1.72'],port=9042)

session = cluster.connect()
```

The error is as follows:

NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.1.72': error(None, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.1.72', 9042)]. Last error: timed out")})

I set the following parameters in the file cassandra.yaml:

```
start_rpc: true

rpc_address: 192.168.1.72

broadcast_rpc_address: 192.168.1.72

listen_address: 192.168.1.72

seed_provider:

    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider

      parameters:

          - seeds: "192.168.1.72"
```

I have also tried with rpc_address: 0.0.0.0 and with many other configurations. The error is always the same. I opened the 9042 port of router and I also tried to connect with port 9160. I disabled the firewall and the antivirus. I tried with python 2 and python 3. I tried with windows 10 and linux. The error is always the same. Obviously with each new configuration I restart cassandra.

I tried the code even on Databricks, but the same error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Cassandra inside a private network? For the driver to connect from Colab, it must be reachable by public IP. Besides opening a port, you would also have to know your public IP as seen from the internet. Port 9160 is the old Thrift port, and will have nothing to do with connecting a modern driver.